# The height to radius ratio of a maximum volume cylinder, inside of a sphere with a radius of r

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have done similar problems where I'm given the radius quite easily, however, I'm running into trouble when doing this problem without any given values.

I get the same answer the person in the video below does, but I am not sure how to cancel the constant r out. I have tried solving for the radius of the cylinder, and then dividing in hopes of cancelling out the r and getting the ratio but I can't seem to figure out how

Let "R" rep radius of cylinder
Let "r" rep radius of sphere

I know Volume of Cylinder = $ πR^2h $
Using Pythagorean theorem I get the relationship that 
$r^2=(\frac{h}{2})^2 + R^2$

After solving for R, then plugging that value into the volume of cylinder equation I get $h=\frac{2r}{\sqrt 3}$

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please could you edit your question so that it's self contained (i.e. all the information to answer it is on this site)

Comment: So you have an answer, are you asking if it's correct?

Comment: I am not sure how to get the ratio of cylinder's height to its radius. I solved for the cylinder's height and got the expression above, which still contains the "r" which represents the radius of the sphere that it is in.

Comment: You need an expression in h and R not h and r